# How do I reduce the app size of an Electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I use the latest Electron version `10.0.3` and created a target for `app` and `mas` (mac-app-store) and I struggle with the size of the app it created.

I found already a few blog posts which cover the topics, but my app size is so unusually high, that I couldn't pinpoint the cause for my situation.

Here is a list of the sizes:

target: `app`

- Electron Framework (130 MB)
- app.asar (**462 MB**)

target: `mas`:

- Electron Framework (130 MB)
- app.asar (**1.1**GB)

Please note, that in the `mas` build the `app.asar` is double the size. First I assumed it now also compiles for the new `arm64` architecture, but it's just the `x86_64`. What could be the reason for these huge app sizes, and why is `mas` double the size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big size of the asar archive is most likely related to the node modules you are using

You can extract app.asar like this

```
npx asar extract app.asar dest
```

Then you can use a tool like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) on the extracted folder to determine the guiltiest modules and you can perhaps remove or replace them

You can also use [modclean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modclean) before packaging to delete unneeded junk that sometimes is included in some modules

Also, make sure to install modules that are only needed in development as `devDependencies` so that `electron-builder` won't package them. `electron` for example, should be in `devDependencies`