# What should I do now in case of decreasing electron app size?

Tags: electron

I am a beginer in electron..I found that electron is a great framework..But app size built with electron is very very big!But as far as I know that VSCode is made with electron..Size of VSCode installed in my pc is almost 293 mb which is almost suitable for me as it has a lot of functionalities included..How did they managed this size?.I don't want to use Visual Studio for this purpose as I don't have so space..What should I do now?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64267856/9698583

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your question is not very clear...

I did not write VS Code so I can not answer how they got it to that size.

It is unclear whether you are asking how to make smaller applications or how to shrink VS Code.

If you are asking how to make smaller applications, then you should use [Neutralinojs](https://neutralino.js.org/). It is like Electron but has a lot less bloat. Which means less storage space is lost.

If you are asking to shrink VS Code you are out of luck, you can't.

Comment: i dont really understand it too but im guessing he is asking how can vscode manage to have a small file size while electron apps sizes are usually very big

Comment: Exactly...I wanted to know how can vscode manage to have a small file size while electron apps sizes are usually very big..I don't want to shrink VS Code......

Comment: @naa I would contact them personally either with a question on their [issue page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) or [email](https://support.microsoft.com/contactus) them.